# ShutdownChannelGroupException at Apache Karaf Shutdown

Tags: apache-karaf, shutdown

I am getting ShutdownChannelGroupException each time when I shutdown Karaf. No matter what I use ' or type 'system:shutdown' or 'logout' to shutdown.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-10" java.nio.channels.ShutdownChannelGroupException
    at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeIndirectly(Invoker.java:210)
    at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeIndirectly(Invoker.java:301)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsAsynchronousServerSocketChannelImpl$AcceptTask.failed(WindowsAsynchronousServerSocketChannelImpl.java:286)
    at sun.nio.ch.Iocp$EventHandlerTask.run(Iocp.java:399)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I tried version **3.0.1/3.0.1** problems comes in both.Also a failure attempt with  setup proxy setting for internet.

```
org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.settings=<USER-HOME>/.m2/settings.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug in Karaf 3.0.1

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KARAF-2924

I believe it is fixed in 3.0.2, although the Jira hasn't been updated.